# Powerbuilder win 64 bit registryget

Tags: windows, 64-bit, powerbuilder

I have a little trouble with windows 64 bit registryget. It does not work on powerbuilder 8.04, and I cant figure it out why. If someone have any suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Though "does not work" is not a very precise description of the problem, i guess it is probably because PB programs are 32 bit, so the registry access is virtualized for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` so the PB application does no "see" the 64 bit part.

You can check what PB has access to by using the 32 bit regedit that should be located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

And if you actually need to manage 64 bit registry from PB, you could declare the native `RegOpenKeyEx` api function as a local external function and access explicitely to the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10533865/317266).